# Python function if else

Tags: python, function

I wrote the below code and tried to run it, but it's not running. Does it have a bug that I can't spot?

```
def greet():
    print('Hi there mister')

kor_Var = input('Enter kor')

if kor_Var != walls:
   print('Incorrect pin')
else:
   greet()
```

Comment: `walls` is not a string, use `'walls'`. Or you didnt show it. 
And what do you mean by `its not running`?

Comment: What is "Kor"? Coordinate?

Comment: What do you mean by *"it's not running"*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change "walls" as string:

```
def greet(): 
    print('Hi there mister')

kor_Var = input('Enter kor')
if kor_Var != "walls":
    print('Incorrect pin') 
else: 
    greet()
```

Comment: This worked fine when I tried it, using either `"walls"` or `'walls'` (Python 3.6.3 (Anaconda)). I don't understand why Jamuhuri Fuschia can't get it to work.

Comment: sorry i took forever to reply. The snippet ran, and am practicing a lot that is why I haven't logged in lately.